# How to view Json objects stored in browser Local storage from Developer tools

Tags: browser, local-storage, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

As in the following snapshot i can view the localStorage data from browser developer tools.
Though **String** values are readable **Json object** is not readable since it is showing as **[object Object]**

Anyone knows a way that i can extract the data in that Json object

[image]

Comment: Devtools shows JSON in localStorage so the problem is that studentDetails was stored incorrectly: apparently the code didn't use JSON.stringify.

Comment: So cannot we store objects?. Is it only allows strings? @wOxxOm

Comment: HTML5 localStorage can only store strings so your code should use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks a lot. Got the answer :)